# Can I install SharePoint Foundation 2010 with full SQL Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, installation

I cannot find out how do I install SharePoint Foundation 2010 with full SQL Server 2008, it seems that installation wizard forces me to use Express edition. Is there a way to use Foundation with normal SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What option are you picking during install?  Single server and then all defaults?  I don't have an installer at hand but picking single server limits your options.   Select server farm even if you only have one server.  That should allow you to use your SQL 2008 install.

I found this link in some training info I had.  [Single Server Install](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/fromthefield/lists/posts/post.aspx?id=112)  Also this [Install info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2009/11/17/installing-sharepoint-server-2010-beta-2-on-a-single-machine.aspx)

Comment: Actually, I tried them all. Server Farm in the end got me closest but I was unable to connect to my localhost where SQL is running. It looks like it requires that SQL is on separate machine and I should be domain?

Comment: It does not requre SQL on a separate system.  It will install.  Is it possible that there is an account issue?  Did you follow guidelines on default accounts?  See edit in OP